# Drools Guvnor on Glassfish error

Tags: glassfish, drools, guvnor

I'm trying to deploy Guvnor (guvnor-5.5.0.Final-tomcat-6.0) to a fresh
glassfish server ( 3.1.2.2 build 5)  and am getting the error below.
I did try the other WARs without any luck and I get the same error on
OSX and windows.

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app :
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/AnnotationProcessor. Please
see server.log for more details
```

Are there any  work-around for this ?

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this?

Comment: Sorry no, I'm trying jboss 7 AS. It doesn't integrate with netbeans though.

Answer (score 0):

Add the jasper-xxx.jar to your lib. It should work. If you deploy in tomcat, it should be in catalina.jar.

Unfortunately JBOSS 7 doesn't use tomcat instead it uses JBossWeb. That's why you have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take the guvnor-5.5.0.Final-jboss-as-7.0.war binary war file

- add dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- remove javassit*.jars
- add resteasy-jaxb-provider-2.2.3.GA.jar
- add resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.3.GA.jar

Add the a glassfish-web.xml file to WEB-INF https://github.com/snowch/glassfish-guvnor/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml

Replace WEB-INF/web.xml with this https://github.com/snowch/glassfish-guvnor/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

Repackage the binary war file and deploy to glassfish