# Steps to deploy Guvnor in Glassfish

Tags: glassfish-3, drools-guvnor

When I had tried deploying Guvnor onto Glassfish, I hit the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684673/drools-guvnor-on-glassfish-error).

If anyone has performed a successful deployment, what are the steps to deploy a recent version of Guvnor (e.g. 5.4) to a recent version of Glassfish (e.g. 3.1)?

Comment: You shouldn't create a new duplicate question if the first one wasn't answered.

Comment: The question is similar, but different.  The previous question is asking for a workaround for a specific problem when deploying guvnor to glassfish.  This question is asking for the ALL of the steps to deploy guvnor to glassfish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps for deploying Guvnor 5.4 are:

1. Take the guvnor-5.4.0.Final-jboss-as-7.0.war binary war file
2. Remove WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.14.0-GA.jar from the binary war file
3. Add the a glassfish-web.xml file to WEB-INF [see here](https://github.com/snowch/glassfish-guvnor/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml)
4. Replace WEB-INF/web.xml with [this](https://github.com/snowch/glassfish-guvnor/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml)
5. Repackage the binary war file and deploy to glassfish

I have a project on git hub that automates creating a glassfish specific version of guvnor.  See here for more information: [link](https://github.com/snowch/glassfish-guvnor)